# WPF - VisualStateManager - How do I?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two states within my VisualStateManagerGroup: "VisualStateLogin".
How do I go from the Base state to another when my Window is loaded?

I Have tried it:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

     //Initializes the mainwindow in a user loogedoff state

     this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
}

void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "LoggedOff", true);
}
```

This is my XAML Code:

```
    <VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>
        <ic:ExtendedVisualStateManager/>
    </VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateLogin">
            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.6000000"/>
            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualState x:Name="LoggedOn"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="LoggedOff">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="brdContent" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0.1"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="brdTab" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0.4"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="brdContent" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.IsHitTestVisible)">
                        <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="True"/>
                    </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="brdTab" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.IsEnabled)">
                        <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="False"/>
                    </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="brdContent" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.IsEnabled)">
                        <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="False"/>
                    </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Thank You

Comment: Are you, per chance, using Blend?

Answer (score 1):

I got to solve it this way:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        //Initializes the mainwindow in a user loogedoff state

        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
    }

    void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ExtendedVisualStateManager.GoToElementState(this.LayoutRoot as FrameworkElement, "LoggedOff", false);        
    }
```

http://jack.ukleja.com/workaround-for-visualstatemanager-gotostate-not-working-on-window/

Answer (score 1):

First: Josimaris Martarellis answer is ok.

But if you have choice, I prefer generating an own UserControl just as the only Root of the Window, and performing VisualStates on this UserControl. So you don't have to rely on ExtendedVisualStateManager and don't have to add extra DLLs to your Project (you have to add "microsoft.expression.interactions.dll" for the "ExtendedVisualStateManager.GoToElementState" solution)